# Efficient way to know region of a coordinate

Tags: python, pandas, performance, segment-tree

everyone, I want to know if there is an efficienct way to know if a coordinate locate in a region. Just like picture below. I want to know each coordinate locate which region below table and get corresponding feature.
[image]

Comment: Anyone can help? Thanks!

Comment: So basically check if start of the first dataframe is between the other dataframes start and end columns? Kindly share sample dataframes with expected output

Comment: The expected output looks like this.
 tCRE_name TSS_start_site.    category
21652 P:r1@PIK3R1 68215761.     5'-UTR
21654 P:r3@PIK3R1 68239844.    3'-UTR
21657 P:r2@PIK3R1 68280356.     CDS
21658 P:r4@PIK3R1 68288098.     CDS

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```py
for s in bladderselecteddf.TSS_Start_Site:
    genes = refdf[ (s >= refdf.Start) & (s <= refdf.End) ].gene_name
```

From your question, it is a little difficult to figure out exactly what you want.